# Add horizontal lines (or text) to individual boxplots when using facet_wrap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I would like to add a horizontal line to each of my boxplots created using the facet_wrap function. This is my code that creates my boxplots:

```
ggplot(data=new.dat, aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free", ncol=4) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) + 
  labs(x="",y="")
```

This is the dataframe that I would like to used for each horizontal line:

```
dat_hlines <- data.frame(cond=c("S1mgg","S2mgg","S3mgg","TOC",
                                "HI","OI","PI","TmaxC"),
                         hline=c(7.5,20,7.5,400,10,10,400,500))
```

This is closest I've got:

```
ggplot(data=new.dat, aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_hline(data=dat_hlines,aes(yintercept=hline)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free", ncol=4) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) + 
  labs(x="",y="")
```

What appears is multiple lines i.e. the same ones duplicated on each boxplot.

What I would like is one line per plot, with each line corresponding with the observations in dat_hlines$hline

p.s. I would have posted graphics but my score doesn't permit.

#### DATA

```
tmp<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
              c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp[1]<-"S1mgg"
tmp[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

tmp2<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
       c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp2[1]<-"S2mgg"
tmp2[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

tmp3<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
       c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp3[1]<-"S3mgg"
tmp3[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

tmp4<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
       c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp4[1]<-"S3mgg"
tmp4[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

tmp5<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
       c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp5[1]<-"TOC"
tmp5[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

tmp6<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
       c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp6[1]<-"HI"
tmp6[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

tmp7<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
       c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp7[1]<-"OI"
tmp7[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

tmp8<- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 200, 2, dimnames=list(c(), 
      c("variable", "value"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp8[1]<-"TmaxC"
tmp8[2]<-rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)

new.dat<-rbind(tmp,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5,tmp6,tmp7,tmp8)
```

Comment: Can you supply the data?

Comment: Yes I can, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where is it? If you want to get help you need to give a reproducible example

Comment: Please excuse the crude coding but...

Comment: ...see above edited text. You will be able to reproduce the problem with 'new.dat' and 'dat_hlines'

Comment: You need to have consistent names in your data. Set `names(dat_hlines)[1] <- "variable"` then it should work...

Comment: Perfect - you're a star. Can you respond above, so it's clear there is closure on the question? Thanks so much. Darren

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
new_data <- merge(new.dat, dat_hlines, by.x = "variable", by.y = "cond")
ggplot(data=new_data, aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot() + 
    facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free", ncol=4) + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) + 
    labs(x="",y="") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = hline))
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: If you use this approach, it is pretty easy to add labels if needed by using `geom_text`.  Just be sure you set `check_overlap = TRUE` if you do.